# OSError: [WinError 123], как решить?

Tags: python, windows

Пока обучаюсь питону и решил написать простенькую прогу которая создаёт файл в нужном нам пути с текстом внутри, сама прога:

```
import os
put=input ("Введите путь до файла")
name=input ("Введите название файла + расширение ")
text=input ("Введите текст")
try:
    os.chdir(put)
except FileNotFoundError:
                         os.mkdir(put)
os.chdir(put)
file=open (name,"w+")
file.write (text)
```

Буду рад если объяснят максимально простым языком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OSError: [WinError 123] Неверный синтаксис имени файла, имени каталога или метки тома
```

Неплохо бы увидеть полный текст ошибки после какого ввода она появляется
Это может возникать здесь:

```
put=input ("Введите путь до файла")

file=open (name,"w+")
```

Сразу после ввода добавьте

```
print(put) 
print(name)
```

И посмотрите, что название файла корректное и по такому пути в windows можно создать файл с указанным именем.
Сам код у вас рабочий.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\f4lln\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.chdir(put)
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: ' F:\\My' Вот ошибка полностью. Добавил после ввода вывод пути и названия файла, выводит, но не более

Comment: Тут всё завязано на тех данных, что вы вводите. нужно ещё видеть ваш ввод в put и name. Вас пробел перед F:\\My не смущает?

Comment: О, заработало после того как путь начал без пробела писать, не можете посоветовать как сделать так, что бы прога кушала безпроблемно пробел?

Comment: Если ответ помог - отметьте его галочкой. Пробелы в начале строки можно удалить методом lstrip(). put.lstrip()